Find all face-recognition matches in JPEG files, which are similar to a corpus of 10 example photos
This code works, with keras_facenet, to find all files in photos/*.jpg matching the face present in me.jpg:
import glob, os, cv2
from keras_facenet import FaceNet
embedder = FaceNet()
detections = embedder.extract("me.jpg", threshold=0.95)
me_emb = detections[0]['embedding']
for f in glob.glob("photos/*.jpg"):
    print(f)
    img = cv2.imread(f)   
    detections, crops = embedder.crop(img, threshold=0.95)
    if detections == []:
        continue
    for j, emb in enumerate(embedder.embeddings(images=crops)):
        dist = embedder.compute_distance(emb, me_emb)
        if dist < 0.7:
            print(f"hey, found in {f=} with {dist=}")

How do to do the same with Keras FaceNet, but with a corpus of multiple example photos me1.jpg, me2.jpg, ..., me10.jpg containing different variations of the face to be found, instead of just one example me.jpg?

Wow, what a flood of downvotes! I did not know it was such a bad question. Could downvoters leave a note about how to improve the question? Is my wording wrong? Is my MCVE wrong? Or the title? Or the tags?

I'm not sure that everyone understood your issue. What a problem to run your script over all me1.jpg, ...me10.jpg in cycle, store the results, sort by distance  and then output them ?
